# Problems running sql queries from Powershell

Tags: mysql, powershell, odbc

I have a script that when I copy and paste the code into a powershell window works fine but when I run the script it pukes. It gives me the error that there are too many odbc connections. Any idea why? here is the background, I have a script that converts excel spreadsheets to csv files in batch. I do this because they are timesheets and it takes only a few seconds to import them into our accounting system as csv files but as excel files importing them takes hours. Then because of the way we calculate sick time our wonderful accounting system can't figure out how to keep track of it. So after converting the timesheets to csv files I read them all and take the data and insert it into mysql database and keep track of it that way.
This is the code that works when I paste it into a powershell window but pukes if I run it as a script.

```
$files =Get-ChildItem $Directory *.csv

$conn = new-object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
$conn.connectionstring = "DSN=dockers"
$conn.open()
   $COUNT = 0

 foreach ($file in $files)
{
Write-Host $file
 $COUNT =  $COUNT +1
$Filename = $file
$end=0
foreach($line in Get-Content $Filename) {
    if ($end -eq 0){
    $row=$line
    $data= $row -split ","
    if ($data[2] -eq "Ttl Hrs:"){ $end = 1} else {
   # write-host $data[0] $data[1] $data[2] $data[3] 
    $query = "Insert into FenTime (Employeecode,Element,TimeType,Hours,PPE,recorddate) values ("+$data[0] + "," +$data[1]+ ",'"+ $data[2] +"'," +$data[3]+",'"+$FileDirectory+"',curdate())"
if (($data[3] -ne "") -and ($data[2] -ne 'OT')) {$cmd = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand($query,$conn)
    $dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    (New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter($cmd)).Fill($dataSet) 
    }
}}
```

Comment: When I pasted this into VSCode it immediately pointed out some missing curly braces. However, in that case can't explain why it would work when pasted into the console.

Comment: I would not recommend using "New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter" in a loop.   If you keep it in the loop you can try to use the .dispose() method. After the New-Object call.  I guessing that this is a resource leak.

Comment: Move this out the loop too. "$dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet"

Comment: "$dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet"  is a com object and you can not many of them before they break.

Comment: Ok sorry I haven't gotten back to this yet but in answer to Steven The { or } missing was because I left out the top part that converts the excel files to csv as well as gets the directory name.

Comment: Aaron, how do you recommend that I move it out of the loop?

Comment: Moving it out of the loop worked Thank you.